# How to dynamically pipe an ng-options?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I currently have this long markup

```
<div class="init-sort">
    <div>sort by:</div>
    <select ng-model="tableSort[0]"
        ng-options="model.Name for model in selectedParameters">
        <option value="">Select</option>
    </select>
</div>
    <div class="sub-sort" ng-show="tableSort[0]">
    <div>then</div>
    <select ng-model="tableSort[1]"
        ng-options="model.Name for model in selectedParameters| filter: {Name:'!' + tableSort[0].Name}">
        <option value="">Select</option>
    </select>
</div>
    <div class="sub-sort" ng-show="tableSort[1]">
    <div>then</div>
    <select ng-model="tableSort[2]"
        ng-options="model.Name for model in selectedParameters| filter: {Name:'!' + tableSort[0].Name} | filter: {Name:'!' + tableSort[1].Name}">
        <option value="">Select</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="sub-sort" ng-show="tableSort[2]">
    <div>then</div>
    <select ng-model="tableSort[3]"
        ng-options="model.Name for model in selectedParameters| filter: {Name:'!' + tableSort[0].Name} | filter: {Name:'!' + tableSort[1].Name} | filter: {Name:'!' + tableSort[2].Name}">
        <option value="">Select</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="sub-sort" ng-show="tableSort[3]">
    <div>then</div>
    <select ng-model="tableSort[4]"
        ng-options="model.Name for model in selectedParameters| filter: {Name:'!' + tableSort[0].Name} | filter: {Name:'!' + tableSort[1].Name} | filter: {Name:'!' + tableSort[2].Name} | filter: {Name:'!' + tableSort[3].Name}">
        <option value="">Select</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

and I want to be able to make it dynamic using through ng-repeat, the problem is that I am having trouble with the filtering part currently to make it dynamic.

Here is what I have currently

```
<div ng-class="{ 'init-sort': $index == 0, 'sub-sort': $index > 0 }" ng-repeat="x in [].constructor(5) track by $index" ng-show="$index == 0 ? true : tableSort[$index - 1]">
    <div>{{$index == 0 ? 'sort by:' : 'then'}}</div>
    <select ng-model="tableSort[$index]"
        ng-options="model.Name for model in ($index == 0 ? (selectedParameters) : (selectedParameters| filter: {Name:'!' + tableSort[0].Name}))">
        <option value="">Select</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

I need help on finishing the filter piping, everything else is currently working as intended